# For loop in python through a list behaves weird when I use the function 'list.remove(item)'

Tags: python, list, for-loop

In my code I have a function where I need to read a list of text files. Some of these files are empty, size = 0. What I needed is detect which file have size = 0, and then remove it from the list. That's simple logic. The problem was that the function list.remove was *not* removing all blank files. And what I did to investigate was basically create a new list where I just append the files with size > 0. And I also created another list called "unused_files" just to compare list sizes afterwards.

```
self.final_files = []
self.unused_files = []

for item in self.files_to_use:
   file_ = item.replace(',', '_')
   file_ = file_.replace('\n','')
   abs_path = os.path.join(self.labels_path, file_ + ".txt")
   file_size = os.path.getsize(abs_path)  

   if(file_size > 0):
       self.final_files.append(item)
   else: 
       self.unused_files.append(item)       

print(len(self.files_to_use))
print(len(self.final_files))
print(len(self.unused_files))
```

The outputs are, in sequence: 3786, 3768 and 18.

With only the list.remove, removing directly from the list, the total would be 3769, letting one empty file in the list.

And just to give it a try, I called the list.remove function after appending the unused files to the unused_files list:

```
self.final_files = []
self.unused_files = []

for item in self.files_to_use:
   file_ = item.replace(',', '_')
   file_ = file_.replace('\n','')
   abs_path = os.path.join(self.labels_path, file_ + ".txt")
   file_size = os.path.getsize(abs_path)  

   if(file_size > 0):
       self.final_files.append(item)
   else: 
       self.unused_files.append(item) 
       self.files_to_use.remove(item)

print(len(self.files_to_use))
print(len(self.final_files))
print(len(self.unused_files))
```

And now, the numbers are: 3769, 3752 and 17. The first output its obvious: the original items were removed from the list, ok. But the second one puzzles me. If all the final files were appended to the final_files list, why the numbers are different? And they are different *exactly* by 17.

Honestly, I've read tons of documentations, and nothing explains this. I do not have any idea of why this is happening.

Comment: Do t edit a list you are iterating over. It throws the indexing off.

Comment: What you mean by "t edit"? Can you explain?

Comment: `remove` shortens the list, but the list iterator being used by the `for` loop isn't notified about that.

Comment: He meant to say "do not edit".

Comment: Never ever ever modify a container you're iterating through, no matter what language.  That's a rule I live by.

Comment: Yes, typo.  "Don't" edit.  Don't change the length by adding OR removing while iterating over it.